# Struggling to style field in orbeon form

Tags: css, styling, orbeon, xforms

I'm quite new to Orbeon and Xforms and am a little rusty with CSS...

I'm trying to reduce the size of an input field (the box that is) on orbeon. I've got the link between control and style.css working by adding:

```
<xh:style type="text/css">
    .short-field {width:25px;}
</xh:style>
```

and then:

```
<xf:input class="short-field" id="control-4-control" bind="control-4-bind">
    <xf:label ref="$form-resources/control-4/label"/>
    <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/control-4/hint"/>
    <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
</xf:input>
```

When I run the form, the field size doesn't change, but by inspecting the code and changing width:25px; to color:red; it makes the text red, so I know its working to some extent, I just can't get it to change the size of the box!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.short-field {width:25px;}`, try `.short-field input {width:25px;}`. This is because for all your XForms controls, in the HTML markup sent to the browser there is a containing element, wrapping the actual HTML input, the field label, and more.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately and when I do "inspect" I can no longer see the CSS class. Very confusing!

Comment: Would you be able to create a minimal example that reproduces the problem, that we can run here, and attach it a response so we can look into it?

Comment: Is there anyway I can direct message u? I can send u the link to see it, but not publicly!

Comment: Are you using Orbeon Forms PE? If the case, then I can set you up in our support system, on which all communications are private.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what that is! You could email me at johotchkiss at @hotmail dot com if ur willing to help further! ;)

Comment: There are [2 versions of Orbeon Forms](http://www.orbeon.com/download): the Professional Edition (PE) and Community Edition (CE). Do you know which one you're using? If it is the PE, then email info AT orbeon.com to be setup on the Orbeon Forms support system, and this way you'll be able to send files privately to support. I hope this helps!